# Python Sharepoint Read List VIEW

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am able to successfully read a Sharepoint Online list using Python's `sharepoint` module.  Per the `sharepoint` documentation, I identify the list using its ID:

`sp_list = site.lists['f1asdfas-9sa12-413b-14a2-c2f12315jf8ea']`

However, using this module, I can only access the default view of the list (which, in my case has certain things filtered out).  I want all items to be shown and captured by `sp_list` above.  Due to reasons out of my control, I cannot change the default view to include all items.

How can I access a sharepoint non-default list view using Python's `sharepoint`?

Thank you.

Comment: Note, I have tried replacing the list ID with a view ID with no success.

Comment: Hi Nick, are you able to share your code? I am getting stuck with various errors and don't know where to start debugging...

Comment: What problem are you running into?  I would post a question, and I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into this...

1. Several people on the official `sharepoint` github repository have [requested](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint/issues/5) this capability
2. A working (no conflicts with master) update has been [submitted](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint/pull/31)
3. The update is simply [awaiting](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint/issues/5#issuecomment-239366252) the module owner to merge the update with master!

I manually updated my local copy of `sharepoint` per the following [updates](https://github.com/m3nu/python-sharepoint/commit/5f9b185b084e25b33b1a2333082f80b62f49180a).  But one can also clone the same unofficial updated version ([here](https://github.com/m3nu/python-sharepoint/tree/5f9b185b084e25b33b1a2333082f80b62f49180a)), and reference that as well.

But, overall, the code owner should merge the working update with master!